How do I solve "realloc(): invalid next size" error?
Here is the section of code where my program crashes:
if (fromNode != toNode) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtxs[fromNode]);
    g->out[fromNode]++;
    if (g->in[toNode].index == g->in[toNode].size) { 
        g->in[toNode].size += 100;
        //printf("Thread:%d, Resizing array of incoming nodes for node %d, size:%d\n", threadID, toNode+1, g->in[toNode].size);
        g->in[toNode].nodes = (int *)realloc(g->in[toNode].nodes, g->in[toNode].size * sizeof(int));
        if (g->in[toNode].nodes == NULL) {
            printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    sortedInsert(g, fromNode, toNode); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtxs[fromNode]);
}

This code is in a loop in a function, run by many threads which reads from a buffer the variables fromNode and toNode and puts them in a struct. The buffer is filled with data read from a file.
When I run this with a small file, everything goes fine. Now I tried with a 15 million-data file, and the program crashed.
The errors vary between executions and are:
mremap_chunk(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)

or
corrupted double-linked list Aborted (core dumped)

or
corrupted size vs. prev_size Aborted (core dumped)

But it always crashes on the realloc after tot milion of iterations.
I tried to run it with Vallgrind
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full -s ./prog

but for some reason it doesn't crash, the output is correct, and valgrind doesn't find any memory leaks or errors.
Maybe the problem is that the size gets too big, and it fills the heap, but why does it work when I run it with valgrind? And how can I solve it?

Have you tried a sanitizer (e.g. ASAN, UBSAN)? Those might help catch errors that Valgrind does not.

This is almost always writing out of bounds somewhere, destroying the heap's book keeping data (like "next size").

The bug is in some code you didn't post. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

You seem to be locking fromNodewith a mutex. Maybe you have the same requirement on toNode (apparently these are linked lists or the like that react allergic to concurrent access.)

As hinted above, the heap is getting corrupted in code not shown, but the corruption isn't detected until realloc is called. I like @tofro idea of perhaps needing to lock toNode. Other common things to look for: freeing the same thing twice (or equivalently, reallocing a previously freed segment), or freeing something but retaining a pointer to it and using it (or equivalently, using an old pointer to something that had been realloced). When you realloc something, you have to be sure that everything that points to it is updated.

Don't use --leak-check=full when you are looking for memory errors. Are you using the most recent version of Valgrind? And what version of Valgrind, which OS and version, compiler and version are you using?

What is the type of g->in[toNode].size? Not a short I hope.
